# How to do navbar fixed?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to do my navbar fixed but it flows left when i add `position:fixed` to css

```
.grid__header {
 position:fixed;
 min-height: 164px;
 height: 164px;
 width:100%;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: flex;
 background: transparent;
 -webkit-flex-direction: row;
 -ms-flex-direction: row;
 flex-direction: row;
 -webkit-justify-content: space-between; /* Safari 6.1+ */
 justify-content: space-between;
}
```

container class doesn't work wihin `.grid__header`. How to fix it?

[Codepen code](http://codepen.io/TsarS/pen/ezvOWV)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you will add `position:fixed` it will move to left, to make it center, add the following CSS to `.grid__header`

`position:fixed; left:0; right:0;`

Comment: `left: 0;` and `right: 0;` is good enough. You don't need to set right and left margin to auto.

Comment: Yes, you right! Thanks. But what to do with z-index (when i open menu - close button doesn't work)?

Comment: @Slip set higher `z-index` for close button it will appear in front. better try google first about `z-index`

Comment: you need to remove the top padding from grid-show-menu class and add top spacing in it, however if you add top spacing you'll have to do something different for that grey overlay bg.

Answer (score 2):

`Position` needs to specify its postion from `left` and `top`.

```css
  .grid__header {
     position:fixed;
    left:0; right:0;
     min-height: 164px;
     height: 164px;
     width:100%;
     display: -webkit-flex;
     display: flex;
    /* background: transparent; */
    
    background:#ccc;
     -webkit-flex-direction: row;
     -ms-flex-direction: row;
     flex-direction: row;
     -webkit-justify-content: space-between; /* Safari 6.1+ */
     justify-content: space-between;
    }
/*##setting height just for display##*/
body{height:1500px;margin:0;padding:0;}
```

```html
<header class="grid__header"></header>
```